# Which template or layout does this line load $this->loadLayout( array('default','marketplace_account_dashboard'));

Tags: layout, template

Magento beginner here. What does this line do:

```
$this->loadLayout( array('default','marketplace_account_dashboard'));
```

? I need to know what does this line do (maybe which controller/layout/template does it load), so that I can go in it and change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that the array contains a list of handles that should be loaded into layout.